# How to open Sublime text using Git Bash Command prompt

Tags: html, github, command-prompt, git-bash, git-repo

```
$ touch hello.html  
$ subl .
bash: subl: command not found
```

I created HTML file using git bash command prompt and I want to open it on Sublime Text 3 using git bash command prompt. But above code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First I had to create new Environment Variable Path. now the code is working.

```
$ cd test1/ 
$ touch hello.html
$ subl hello.html
```

or `$ subl`

Following youtube video might be helpful.
[How to Open Sublime Text 3 from Command Prompt in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWOYqoLPPyU)